# Can index.number_of_replicas be set as a static index setting in ES v2.x?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

In elasticsearch v1.x I could set `index.number_of_replicas` statically (in the elasticsearch.yml file):

```
# Set the number of replicas (additional copies) of an index (1 by default):
index.number_of_replicas: 0
```

However, I am now putting together the config files for v2.3 and this setting no longer has any effect.

For example, if I add the above code to the elasticsearch.yml file and fire up ES v2.3, the Marvel indices are still automatically created with `number_of_replicas: 1`. It also isn't listed with the static settings [in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/index-modules.html).

Has it changed since v1.x, or am I doing something wrong? Can this only be done via the dynamic settings now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That static setting still works in 2.3. You can try by simply creating a new index without specifying any settings:

```
PUT /test/test/1
```

In the logs, you'll see something like:

```
[2016-05-30 05:49:45,836][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [dev-node-1] [test] creating index, cause [auto(index api)], templates [], shards [2]/[0], mappings [test]
```

`[2]/[0]` means that by default I've set two primary shards and 0 replicas shards to be created.

If you see replica shards in your Marvel indices, it's because there must be a [`.marvel-es` template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/configuration.html#config-marvel-indices) which specifies different index settings.